Ubuntu 22.04 installation using autoinstall
I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 Server using PXE boot. I have configured my user-data to the following:



However, I keep getting this error when I boot my bare metal server (I am running this in VirtualBox for testing purposes):

If anyone can help, thank you!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Also, please include the actual text instead of screenshots of it. Screenshots don't allow users that want to help you copy and paste text to test it.

The problem lies in the formatting of mirror-selection. Looking at the error message, you'll see that it starts to process apt-config with regards to Mirror, but it finishes with an error:
start: subiquity/Mirror/cmd-apt-config: curtin command apt-config
finish: subiquity/Mirror/apply_autoinstall_config: Command '['systemd-run', '--wait', '--same-dir', '--property', 'SyslogIdentifier=subiquity_log.2129', '--property', 'PrivateMount=yes', '--setenv', 'PATH=/snap/subiquity/5495/bin:/snap/subiquity/5496/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/subiquity/5495/bin:/snap/subiquity/5495/sbin', '--setenv', 'PYTHONPATH=:/snap/subiquity/5495/lib/python3.10/site-packages', '--setenv', /snap/subiquity/5495/usr/bin/python3.10', '-m', 'curtin', '--showtrace', '-vvv', '--set', 'json:reporting={"subiquity": {"type": "journald", "identifier": "curtin_event.2199.1"}}', '-c', '/var/log/installer/subiquity-curtin-apt.conf', 'apt-config', '-t', '/tmp/tmpzni38iqq/mount']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Looking at your config, you currently have arches at the same level as primary, but it works together with the mapping of uri. So the following is incorrect:
mirror-selection:
 primary:
 - country-mirror
 - arches:
   - amd64
   - i386
   uri: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
 - arches:
   - s390x
   - arm64
   - armhf
   - powerpc
   - ppc64el
   - riscv64
   uri: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports

If you look at Autoinstall configuration reference manual, it says:

In the new format, the primary section expects a list of mirrors,
which can be expressed in two different ways:

The special country-mirror value

A mapping with the following keys:

uri (Required): The URI of the mirror to use, e.g., http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu.

arches (Optional): A list of architectures supported by the mirror. By default, this list contains the current CPU architecture.





And the example it gives:
# Use the first custom mirror that works. Do not restrict to specific architectures.
autoinstall:
  apt:
    mirror-selection:
      primary:
        - uri: "http://mirror1.internal/ubuntu"
        - uri: "http://mirror2.internal/ubuntu"

# Use one mirror for amd64 and another for i386.
autoinstall:
  apt:
    mirror-selection:
      primary:
        - uri: "http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu"
          arches: [amd64]
        - uri: "http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu"
          arches: [i386]

Therefore, the mapping of the keys, uri and arches, are grouped together. So edit your user-data file so the mirror-selection section is as follows:
mirror-selection:
 primary:
  - country-mirror
  - uri: "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/"
    arches: [amd64, i386]
  - uri: "http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports"
    arches: [s390x, arm64, armhf, powerpc, ppc64el, riscv64]

Additionally, you have the following section under apt:
 security:
 - arches:
   uri: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
 - arches:
   uri: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports

This should be removed, because security is not a valid key under apt. At least I don't think it is, because I cannot find any documentation regarding this key.
More observations:

Under ssh:

you have defined instal-server: false. First, instal-server should be install-server.
Also, this configuration will not install openssh. Is this what you want?


Under source:

You have defined search_drivers: false. The default is true. Is this what you want? Quoting the documentation:

The default is true for most installations, and false when a “core
boot” or “enhanced secure boot” method is selected (where third-party
drivers cannot be currently installed).





So your complete user-data file should be:
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
 version: 1
 locale: en_US.UTF-8
 keyboard:
  layout: us
  toggle: null
 apt:
  disable_components: []
  fallback: continue-anyway
  geoip: true
  mirror-selection:
   primary:
    - country-mirror
    - uri: "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/"
      arches: [amd64, i386]
    - uri: "http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports"
      arches: [s390x, arm64, armhf, powerpc, ppc64el, riscv64]
  preserve_sources_list: false
 codecs:
  install: false
 drivers:
  install: false
 identity:
  hostname: sima
  realname: sima
  username: sima
  password: [enter encrypted password here]
 kernel:
  package: linux-generic
 network:
  ethernets:
   enp0s3:
    critical: false
    dhcp-identifier: mac
    dhcp4: true
  verssion: 2
 oem:
  install: true
 source:
  id: ubuntu-server
  search-drivers: false
 ssh:
  allow-pw: true
  authorized-keys []
  install-server: false
 updates: security


Perhaps use quotes for the argument of the uri parameter? As seen for example here:
# Use the first custom mirror that works. Do not restrict to specific architectures.
autoinstall:
  apt:
    mirror-selection:
      primary:
        - uri: "http://mirror1.internal/ubuntu"
        - uri: "http://mirror2.internal/ubuntu"

# Use one mirror for amd64 and another for i386.
autoinstall:
  apt:
    mirror-selection:
      primary:
        - uri: "http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu"
          arches: [amd64]
        - uri: "http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu"
          arches: [i386]


Example from: https://canonical-subiquity.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/reference/autoinstall-reference.html


hmm,, what do you mean ?

Yes David. You're right. Next time, I will include the answer.
